# How to check if provided properties belongs to generics object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with TypeScript generics. I wrote simple useMergeableState React hook that updates state by merge. I wanted not to be possible to add new keys, so newState parameter is Partial of T.

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';

type Return<T> = [T, (newState: T) => void, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>];

export default function useMergeableState<T extends object>(initialState: T): Return<T> {
    const [state, setState] = useState<T>(initialState);

    const updateState = (newState: Partial<T>) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            ...newState,
        });
    };

    return [state, updateState, setState];
}
```

Now I try to update state with only part of object

```
interface FormState {
    amount: string;
    paid: string;
}

const [state, updateState] = useMergeableState<FormState>({
    amount: "1",
    paid: "2"
});

updateState({
   amount: "5"
});
```

And now updateState returns me an error

> Property 'paid' is missing in type '{ amount: string; }' but required in type 'FormState'.ts(2345)

Property paid is required in interface, but not in updateState because of Partial. How can I write it then?

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-tharp-tobz4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotted the issue. It is located in `Return<T>` type, its different then what your really return. Consider what is there and what should be:

```
// is
type Return<T> = [
  T,
  (newState: T) => void, // here is T and should be Partial<T>
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
];
// should be
type Return<T> = [
  T,
  (newState: Partial<T>) => void, // changed to Partial<T>
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>
];
```

**BTW.** You don't need this type at all, if you will remove `: Return<T>` from function it will infer it fully correctly if you will use `as const`:

```
return [state, updateState, setState] as const
```

Comment: Oh god, of course...I am so blind. I thought I have some logic problem. Thank you, Maciej.

However, it wont't infer return correctly when removed. I don't know why, but it treats the return like regular array with union type rather than tuple.

Comment: Yes sorry append to return `as const` and will infer correctly `return [state, updateState, setState] as const`